# Changing the default view in OOWriter "Save As..." Dialog

Tags: windows, openoffice-writer

I often have this workflow:  Open an OpenOffice Writer file from the File Explorer, then "Save As..." as a different, similarly named, document into the same folder.  For instance, opening `foobarbaz_TEMPLATE` and saving it as `foobarbaz_20140424_001`.

I do this a lot every day, and every time I do, I have to change the view in the "Save As..." dialog from small icons to detail, and then sort by filename, so I can see if I already have a `foobarbaz_20140424_001` or a `foobarbaz_20140424_002` or whatever, so I can name the file next in the sequence.

Is there some way for me to default the "Save As..." dialog's view to be the one I have been changing it to manually each time?

Comment: Hmm - if you just want to **rename** the file without editing it, there would be easier ways than opening OOo.Writer every time.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Of course, but, alas, editing it is entirely the point of what I'm doing.